# Computing the MD5 hash of an integer in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, md5

I need to compute a hash of an integer using python 3. Is there a cleaner and more efficient solution than the following?

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> N = 123
>>> hashlib.md5(str(N).encode("ascii")).hexdigest()
'202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70'
```

It seems weird to have to convert to a unicode string, then decode it to a byte array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cryptographic hash such as MD5 can only be applied to bytes. There are more efficient ways of encoding a number as bytes, but you still need to follow the contract.

```
>>> hashlib.md5(int(-123).to_bytes(8, 'big', signed=True)).hexdigest()
'fc1063e1bcb35f0d52cdceae4626c39b'
```

Comment: Great, thanks Ignacio. I didn't know you could call methods on ints.  Do you know how to do this in python 2 by any chance?

Comment: For Python 2.x you need to use `struct` to pack it into a bytestring.

Comment: Yikes.  One more reason to prefer python 3, then. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Ignacio's answer is perfect, but in case you need the code to work with both python 2 and python 3, and if you have NumPy installed, then this works great:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import hashlib.md5
>>> N = 123
>>> hashlib.md5(np.int64(N)).hexdigest()
'f18b8dbefe02a0efce281deb55a209cd'
```